# Vue Firebase: get query range from specific record to the last record

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get all the records from a specific record to the last record in my database.

```
    ref.orderByChild("date").equalTo("19/11/2020 @ 19:50:29").on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
```

This query gives me the specified record but i need all the records from this one to the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called `startAt`, which starts at a given node and then returns all nodes until the end (or until the `endAt` condition you added).

So something like:

```
ref.orderByChild("date").startAt("19/11/2020 @ 19:50:29")
```

Note that your date format is not great for this type of sorting. You might want to consider a date format where the lexicographical order is chronological too, such as `"2020-11-19T19:50:29"`.

Comment: This query gives me the wrong records probably because, as you mentioned, the date string isn't chronological. Is there a way to get all the records from the record where the string is equal to "19/11/2020 @ 19:50:29" until the first  child added or do i need to rewrite the date format into "2020-11-19T19:50:29"?

Comment: In your current format there is no way to get a single slice of nodes that are chronologically contiguous across multiple days. You can get all nodes for a single day, but nothing longer.  To allow that, you'll need to change the format in your keys to something like what I said at the end of my answer.